# minitest-spec-rails causes all controller tests to fail with NoMethodError: undefined method `safe_constantize' for "UsersController":String

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, minitest

I tried dropping minitest-spec-rails into an existing Rails 3.0 project, but all controller tests fail with errors like NoMethodError: undefined method `safe_constantize' for "UsersController":String

Has anyone else encountered this?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that minitest-spec-rails requires rails 3.2+ rather than supporting 3.0.

Answer (score 0):

The [minitest-rails](https://github.com/blowmage/minitest-rails) gem supports Rails 3.0 as of version 0.1 release in July, 2012. Before that it required 3.1+.